# R - find closest business day (czech)

Tags: r, lubridate

I need to create a function that will return next closest business days. For today (`2019-07-09`) the result would be `2019-07-10` since tomorrow is not a business holiday or a weekend. In case that tomorrow would be a business holiday, the result should be `2019-07-11` but in case that this day will be weekend/holidays, the result should be the closest working day.

Here is a list of local business holidays. Between that two days in April are Easter eve and dates are variable but I'll fix it on my own in future.

```
business_holidays <- c("01-01", "04-19", "04-22", "05-01", "05-08", "07-05", "07-06", 
    "09-28", "10-28", "11-17", "12-24", "12-25", "12-26")
```

Here is what I created yet.

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(lubridate) 

df <- data.frame(
      date=seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-12-31"), "days")
      ) %>% 
      mutate(
        weekend = if_else(wday(date) %in% c(7, 1), 1, 0),

        business_holiday = if_else(
          format(date, "%m-%d") %in% business_holidays & weekend == 0,
          1, 0),

        next_business_dt = date + 1
      )
```

`next_business_dt` is not correct since next day might be a weekend (1 or 2 days) and the closest Monday could be a business holiday. These business holidays might be even more than just one day, for example Christmas eve - in 2017 there was a weekend and then 3 days Christmas eve holidays.

Comment: look at [bizdays](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bizdays/bizdays.pdf) package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible solutions is to use the `fill()` function of the `tidyr` package.

First, fill the `next_business_dt` column with a date if it is a working day and with NA if the day corresponds to a weekend or a holiday:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(
      date = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-12-31"), "days")
      ) %>% 
      mutate(
        weekend = if_else(wday(date) %in% c(7, 1), 1, 0),

        business_holiday = if_else(
          format(date, "%m-%d") %in% business_holidays & weekend == 0,
          1, 0),

        next_business_dt = ifelse((weekend | business_holiday),
                NA, format(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
              )

      )
```

Then to fill the `next_business_dt` column with the closest next non-NA date:

```
res <- df %>% fill(next_business_dt, .direction = "up")
```

It works like that:

> `date weekend business_holiday next_business_dt
>   1  2019-01-01       0                1       2019-01-02
>   2  2019-01-02       0                0       2019-01-02
>   3  2019-01-03       0                0       2019-01-03
>   4  2019-01-04       0                0       2019-01-04
>   5  2019-01-05       1                0       2019-01-07
>   6  2019-01-06       1                0       2019-01-07
>   7  2019-01-07       0                0       2019-01-07`

Although, if the last day or days of the year are not working days (as it is the case for 2017), the NAs will remain in some last rows of the `next_business_dt`. It may be resolved, for example, if we extend the date sequence to some days in the next year and then cut the result.